# What to do with excess Great Generals in G+K?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I'm playing for a Conquest victory in G+K.
Before G+K, when Great Generals start popping up, I would use 2 or 3 for combat and rest for Golden Age. G+K altered the Great Person mechanics so much that I have to unlearn the above strategy.

The only non-combat function is building a Citadel and convert surrounding tiles into your territory. I have limited use for this feature and all I can do is to park each one into my cities.

Can anyone suggest a better way to dispose excess GG under G+K?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an unprotected general to lure out an enemy unit. On destroying that enemy unit, it could make the difference in a successful offence or defence campaign.

**Delete them, as they cost you money.**
Proof
Two generals and state of finance.

[image]
[image]

After Deleting two generals. Saving 4G @ 2G per general.

[image]

Comment: Using excess generals (& workers) as bait does make a good strategy during wartime.

Comment: Great People do not generate unit maintenance costs, so that bit of conjecture is inaccurate.

Comment: thanks for commenting. amended. harsh down vote by the way. hope you reconsider

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh non-combat units - such as workers and great people - do have maintenance cost.

Comment: @Oak Everything I've read at CivFanatics explicitly disagrees.

Comment: After some searching; I am standing with the argument that great people, like workers, have a maintenance cost.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Just open a game and see, they do have maintenance costs.

Answer (score 6):

I honestly find that, prior to the Modern Era and the advent of air bombardment, Great Generals in excess of the number you need to cover your entire invasion force in the 15% aura are best served to plop down Citadels outside of cities you are sieging that are particularly tough to crack, assuming you have nearby territory. Not only does this give a +100% Defensive Strength boon to whoever stands in it, it gives you an area of your territory that you can have units in, which if you have units with the March/Repair promotions, means that you're getting +20 HP per turn versus +10. This can help keep your siege weapons and/or archers far healthier in long wars.

If you're playing Sweden, you can always just pop them into City-States for the +90 Influence bonus.

Answer (score 3):

I always use excess GGs to steal territory and key resources from an AI that already dislikes me (to avoid the diplomatic penalty applying to a friend). You do this by constructing a citadel which acts exactly like the culture bomb did in vanilla Civ5.

Comment: +1. To elaborate. If you construct a citadel within or beside your cultural border, the tile and adjacent tiles will become part of your cultural border. If the adjacent tiles are of an opposing nation or city state, your culture will take over those tiles too.